# How to detect mouse clicked location on an image with custom shaped cursor in c++

Tags: c++, windows, windows-forms-designer, custom-component

In my problem, there is an image and I need to give user to select some specific location within that image. For that I need to provide a square shape(customized by myself-widths and heights) with the cursor. Then user just wanted to place that on the location of the given image and click. Then I want take that locations. Can anyone with such experiences please guide me with sample code in c++ windows forms.

Comment: You need some GUI library, since standard C++11 don't know about GUIs. Consider perhaps [Qt](http://qt.io/) which is cross-platform

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an ideal way of solving this problem. refer this source

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "test.h"

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>

IplImage* frame, *img1;
CvPoint point;
int drag = 0;
CvCapture *capture = 0;
int key = 0;
CvRect rect;

void mouseHandler(int event, int x, int y, int flags, void* param)
{
    /* user press left button */
    if (event == CV_EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN && !drag)
    {
        point = cvPoint(x, y);
        drag = 1;
    }
    /* user drag the mouse */
    if (event == CV_EVENT_MOUSEMOVE && drag)
    {
        img1 = cvCloneImage(frame);
        cvRectangle(img1, point, cvPoint(x, y), CV_RGB(255, 0, 0), 1, 8, 0);
        cvShowImage("result", img1);
    }
    /* user release left button */
    if (event == CV_EVENT_LBUTTONUP && drag)
    {
        rect = cvRect(point.x, point.y, x - point.x, y - point.y);
        cvSetImageROI(frame, rect);
        cvShowImage("result", frame);
        drag = 0;
    }

    /* user click right button: reset all */
    if (event == CV_EVENT_RBUTTONUP)
    {
        drag = 0;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(0);
    if (!capture)
    {
        printf("Cannot open initialize webcam!\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    /* create a window for the video */
    cvNamedWindow("result", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

    while (key != 'q')
    {
        frame = cvQueryFrame(capture);
        if (rect.width>0)
            cvSetImageROI(frame, rect);
        cvSetMouseCallback("result", mouseHandler, NULL);
        key = cvWaitKey(10);
        if ((char)key == 'r') { rect = cvRect(0, 0, 0, 0); cvResetImageROI(frame); }
        cvShowImage("result", frame);
    }
    cvDestroyWindow("result");
    cvReleaseImage(&img1);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that use VTK toolkit as it has cursor position location but make sure that your image top left corner is positioned with VTK's (world co-ordinate system's) (0,0) or if you do not want to position image that way then you need to maintain offset and use this offset to add/subtract when you get mouse position. In beginning you can refer below link as how VTK cursor position code works:

http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/Interaction/ClickWorldCoordinates

Comment: can I use the customized shape(square) as the cursor?

Comment: Why not ? This may help you:http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/Visualization/Cursor2D